# Сортировка NSArray в алфавитном порядке

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Всем доброго дня!

У меня есть два `NSArray`, оба наполнены строковыми объектами `NSString`. Один из массивов - строками русского алфавита (кириллица), второй массив - строками сербского алфавита (латиница, но в нем есть много символов с диграфами). Как отсортировать эти массивы в алфавитном порядке? Судя по всему

```
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

сортирует только по английскому алфавиту, или это не так?

Заранее весьма благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кириллицу оно сортирует прекрасно - там ведь простое сравнение номером символов в таблице Unicode.

---

А вот с диграфами сложнее. Все зависит от того, представлены ли они действительно как единый символ или как два раздельных.
Боюсь, что всё же второй вариант - тогда нужно просто перед сортировкой перевести эти двухбуквенные сочетания в "настоящие диграфы", благо, в Unicode и для них место нашлось:

```
#define _DŽ = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C4];
#define _Dž = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C5];
#define _dž = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C6];

#define _LJ = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C7];
#define _Lj = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C8];
#define _lj = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01C9];

#define _NJ = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01CA];
#define _Nj = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01CB];
#define _nj = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C", 0x01CC];
```

Конвертируется это дело просто, вот пример небольшой тестовой программы:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// clang -framework Foundation -o convert_digraphs convert_digraphs.m

static NSArray *sourceLiterals = nil;
static NSArray *unicodedLiterals = nil;

static void initArrays(void)
{
    NSString *srcLit = @"DŽ-Dž-dž-LJ-Lj-lj-NJ-Nj-nj";
    sourceLiterals = [srcLit componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *unicd = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%C-%C-%C-%C-%C-%C-%C-%C-%C",
             0x01C4, 0x01C5, 0x01C6, 0x01C7, 0x01C8, 0x01C9, 0x01CA, 0x01CB, 0x01CC];
    unicodedLiterals = [unicd componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    assert(sourceLiterals && unicodedLiterals);
}

int main (void) 
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    initArrays();
    NSMutableString * test = [@"DŽ dž NJ Lj" mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Source string : '%@'", test);
    NSLog(@"Replacing two-glyphs chars with digraphs..."); 
    /* 
       Для обратной замены на двухбуквенные сочетания 
       нужно просто поменять местами массивы sourceLiterals и unicodedLiterals
     */
    [sourceLiterals enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [test replaceOccurrencesOfString: obj
                              withString: [unicodedLiterals objectAtIndex: idx]
                                 options: NSLiteralSearch 
                                   range: NSMakeRange(0, [test length])];

    }];
    NSLog(@"Result : '%@'", test);
    [test release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Проверил: при помощи -localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:   сортируются и русские и сербские слова, но в сербском символы с диграфами записываются как два символа в кодировке и потому находятся в списке произвольно в перемешку с аналогичными без диграфа. Буду внедрять методику описанную выше. Большое спасибо за ответ и реальный совет!

Comment: @AlexThumb, если будет что-то непонятно в коде - спрашивайте, я его писал уже глубокой ночью :)  
Ну и не забывайте принимать ответ, если он вам помог.

Comment: Все достаточно ясно, большое спасибо!  Забыл отметить, исправился)